# question about line integral in a strength field

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

Let the field strength $\bar{F}(x,y) = e^xy ·\vec{i} , ((x,y) \in R^2)$. How can I prove, without doing any calculations, that the line integer of $\bar{F}$ along the segment joining $(2,0)$ with $(2,4)$ is zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$C:x=2$, $0\leq y\leq 4$, so $dx=0$. Thus the integral is zero since $\int_C\vec F\cdot d\vec r=\int_Ce^xydx$.